# Regex to capture group name on first line, then the corresponding value on the next?

Tags: regex, regex-group, splunk

I'm after a regex that will enable me to capture the name of the mailbox within the first line, then the corresponding value as a 'count' group after the carriage return. The below is a sample, there are roughly 14 mail addresses in total;

```
Protection.admin@test.com
705
Go.live@test.com
14
ABCpremier@test.com
29
reassuredtest.com
20
lifetest@test.com
8
```

I have used Rubular and I'm able to capture the values of the 'count' so to speak, but when using this then in splunk - I'm only capturing the first value of 705 as I believe it's falling foul of the '.' in 'Go.live';

```
[a-z\.]+@test.com\r\n](?<count>[^\n\r]+)
```

Would someone kindly assist me in a query that would cycle through, capture the mailbox name as one capture group, then the count value that proceeds it?

Comment: How about e.g. [`\S+test\.com\r?\n(?<count>\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/HFp4Kb/1)

Comment: Are the 14 email addresses in one event or multiple events?  Are the counts in the same event as the email address or a different one?

Comment: Thanks for the responses - these are presented in one event, so the extraction would require to capture the email address and then the value, resulting in 14 instances of both

Comment: @bobblebubble - that worked, but similar to my attempt - it only finds the first value of 705

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get more than the first match from a regex in Splunk you must use the `max_match` option to the `rex` command.  Once all of the mailbox names and counts are extracted, they're paired up, split into separate events, and then broken apart again.  If you try to split the events without pairing up the names and counts then you'll lose the association between the name and its count.

Here's a run-anywhere example query.  Note that I had to fix the fourth email address.

````
| makeresults | eval _raw="Protection.admin@test.com
705
Go.live@test.com
14
ABCpremier@test.com
29
reassured@test.com
20
lifetest@test.com
8"
```Commands above create demo data.  Delete IRL```
```Extract the mailbox names and counts```
| rex max_match=0 "(?<mailbox>[^@]+)@[\s\S]+?(?<count>\d+)"
```Combine each mailbox name with its count```
| eval results=mvzip(mailbox,count)
```Remove line ends```
| eval results=trim(results,"
")
```Separate each name/count pair into their own events```
| mvexpand results
```Break out the mailbox and count values into separate fields again```
| eval results=split(results,",")
| eval mailbox=mvindex(results, 0), count=mvindex(results, 1)
```Display the results```
| table mailbox count
````

Comment: That's awesome Rich, thank you. I hadn't thought about max_match within the regex, you hero. I need to tidy up the eval a little but this is working as hoped. Thank you again!